# Is there any way to close your own question

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

I have asked a question and satisfied with the answers. I have ticked one of them. Is there any way in which i can "close" the question to further answering or is there any convention on what i should put in the title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, you've done everything you need to do already. Please don't edit the title to add "solved" or anything like that, that's not how this site works.

Questions are never "closed" to further answers. You never know when a new, useful answer could be posted. Your ticking (accepting) of one of the answers is enough to mark the question as answered, nothing else is needed.